# Airsoft Hollywood flavour of Lua - OpenDisplay problems in 68k

Tags: video, lua, 68000

In Airsoft's Hollywood flavour of Lua, I'm having trouble with the OpenDisplay function:

```
Code: Select all
    @DISPLAY 1, { X=#CENTER, Y=#CENTER, borderless=True, width=800, height=300, noclose=True, Color = #WHITE }
    @DISPLAY 2, { Title = "Window 2", X=10, Y=10, width=560, height=540, hidden=True, Color= #WHITE }
    @DISPLAY 3, { Title = "Window 3",X=600, Y=200,width=1000, height=400,noclose=True, hidden=True, Color= #WHITE }
    @DISPLAY 4, { Title = "Window 4",X=400, Y=1,width=1024, height=580, noclose=True,hidden=True, Color= #WHITE }

     ///Display 1         

    OpenDisplay (4)
    OpenDisplay (3)
    OpenDisplay (2)
```

The code above runs nicely on MorphOS (native) and Windows, but if I export and run as a 68k binary then it fails.

The System complains that it is unable to change display size to 1024x580 and others.

This is also a problem on not only all 68k system inc. WinUAE emulated systems, but also Trance under MorphOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen borders are a limitation on "non hacked" OS3 and the size of the window and the position need to be considered.

Remember that on OS3 windows cannot be moved outside of the screen's boundaries.

MorphOS and OS4 allow windows to be moved outside of the screen's boundaries, but OS3 strictly disallows it.

The solution is to make your screen at least 1424x581 pixels to accomodate your window in OS3.

Always maintain that the screen is large enough to accommodate the display.